# How do I route based on a url parameter in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using Sinatra and I want to use something like a referrer code in my urls that will somewhat control access and identify the provenance of a given URL.

```
/secret-code/rest/of/path
```

should be rejected if "secret-code" is not in a predetermined list.

I want to use route conditions

```
set(:valid_tag) { |tag| condition { tag === 'abcd' } }

get '/:tag', :valid_tag => params[:tag] do 
  'Hello world!'
end
```

but params is not in scope. Do I need to dispatch in the block? What is the best way to handle multiple routes without having to duplicate the tag checking logic in each one?

```
/secret/route1/
/secret/route1/blah
/secret/route2/
```

Is there a way to chain handlers? Can I do

```
 get /:tag/*
      # check :tag
      redirect_to_handler(params[:splat])
```

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of things it looks like you're trying to make use of Sinatra's named parameters.  Params is only in scope within the block:

```
get '/:secret_code/*' do
    redirect_to_handler unless secret_codes.include? params[:secret_code]
end
```

The code above assumes you have a collection of 'secret_codes' that you're going to check with the secret_code from the URL.

Comment: The problem is in matching the rest of the route: "redirect_to_handler params[:splat]" then I can't use Sinatra's route matching anymore. I guess I have to parse the path and then dispatch manually? That would be pretty unpleasant.

Comment: In that case couldn't you just use Sinatra's redirect method? ie. redirect params[:splat] unless secret_codes.include? params[:secret_code].  That should continue using Sinatra's route matching for whatever the path matched was in the splat.

Comment: I'd put this in a `before` filter instead of a route, like the [`authenticate!` example in the Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters). It's clearer what the intention is for one, and you don't have to bother with duplicated route paths and all that.

Comment: @ianin: I like your answer the best. If you write it as a comment instead of an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question)

Sinatra matches the lexically first rule and you can pass onto the next matching rule using 'pass'. So something like this works as long as it is the first rule that would match.

```
get '/:tag/*' do
  halt_if_bad_tag params[:tag]
  pass
end

get '/:tag/route1' do
   'hello world'
end
```